# Does a server-side GitHub repository have a HEAD?

Tags: github

Do GitHub repositories (the ones on GitHub's servers that I clone to my local computer) have a HEAD? If so, how can I view it?

Just to emphasize: once I clone a repository to my local machine, the repository has a HEAD, which I can view by `cd`-ing into the repository's working directory and running `cat .git/HEAD`. What I'm is asking about is the situation on GitHub's servers.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? What problem do you have that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @mason: No problem. I'm just trying to understand the Git model. Are all repositories basically the same, or are there two kinds: server-side (that, for instance, don't have a HEAD and maybe have other characteristics that distinguish them from client-side repositories) and client-side.

Comment: It's irrelevant. If you managed to SSH/RDP/Powershell/VNC or somehow get a command line session on one of GitHub's servers, you'd probably find a HEAD. But it doesn't really matter, because you won't be doing that.

Comment: @mason: So all operations vis-a-vis a GitHub server must specify a branch, correct?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. You can certainly interact with tags and check out specific commits without having a branch. Why are you asking? GitHub is Git running on a remote server with a nice UI on top of it, with additional features for Pull Requests/Issues/Wikis.

Comment: @mason: OK. Thanks. This was helpful. I wasn't aware you can specify individual commits that are not pointed at by a branch.

Comment: That has nothing to do with GitHub. The same is true of Git running on your computer, or GitLab, or anything else Git. Git is Git.

Comment: @mason: And in the Git model, all repositories have the same basic structure, right? For instance, all of them have a HEAD? There is no distinction between server-side repositories and client-side repositories. Is this correct?

Comment: Git is distributed version control. There's no distinction between client and server. It's more like peer to peer. Now, we often use GitHub as a server, but that's just usage. The software is still the same. Let's say GitHub shuts off tomorrow. As long as I've got the repository on my machine, I can just tell people "hey, use the Git hosted on my machine at X url" and  they can pick right back up where they left off. I think you're focusing far too much on this HEAD thing. Git is Git, no matter where it is.

Comment: @mason: Got it. Many thanks.